# Procedural Texturing Checkerboard OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, shader

I encounter some difficulties to implement a procedural texture of checkerboard. Here is what I need to get:

[image]

Here is what i get:

[image]

It's close but my texture is kind of rotated in respect of what I need to get.

Here is the code of my shader:

```
#version 330

in vec2 uv;

out vec3 color;

uniform sampler1D colormap;

void main() {
    float sx = sin(10*3.14*uv.x)/2 + 0.5;

    float sy = sin(10*3.14*uv.y)/2 + 0.5;

    float s = (sx + sy)/2;


    if(true){
            color = texture(colormap,s).rgb;
     }
```

colormap is a mapping from 0 to 1, where 0 correspond to red, 1 to green.

I think the problem is coming from the formula i use, (sx+sy)/2 . I need to get the square not rotated but aligned with the border of the big square.
If someone has an idea to get the good formula.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
float sx = sin(10.0 * M_PI * uv.x);
float sy = sin(10.0 * M_PI * uv.y);
float s = sx * sy / 2.0 + 0.5;
```

Example (without texture):
https://www.shadertoy.com/view/4sdSzn

Answer (score 1):

You can add a rotation operation to "uv":

```
mat2 R(float degrees){
    mat2 R = mat2(1);
    float alpha = radians(degrees);
    R[0][0] =  cos(alpha);
    R[0][1] =  sin(alpha);
    R[1][0] = -sin(alpha);
    R[1][1] =  cos(alpha);
    return R;
}

void main(){
    ver2 new_uv = R(45) * uv;
    float sx = sin(10*3.14*new_uv.x)/2 + 0.5;
    float sy = sin(10*3.14*new_uv.y)/2 + 0.5;
    float s = (sx + sy)/2;
    color = texture(colormap,s).rgb;
}
```